# Is this proof of $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A\land x\in B\}$ correct?

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

If $\{x:\varphi (x)\}=y\iff (\forall x)(x\in y\iff x\in \{x:\varphi (x)\})$,

then by definition of membership of a bracketed set,

$\{x:\varphi (x)\}=y\iff (\forall x)(x\in y\iff \varphi (x))$

letting $\varphi (x)=x\in A \land x\in B$ and $y=A\cap B$ then,

$\{x:x\in A\land x\in B\}=A\cap B\iff (\forall x)(x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A\land x\in B)$

by properties of the intersection,

$\{x:x\in A\land x\in B\}=A\cap B\iff (\forall x)(x\in A \land x\in B\iff x\in A\land x\in B)$

Q.E.D

For reference, I'm reading Patrick Suppes's book on axiomatic set theory and this proof was left as an exercise to the reader. He gives the definition of the intersection of sets as $A\cap B=y\iff (\forall x)(x\in y\iff x\in A\land x\in B)$. He later then defines the notation of bracketed sets. He does give the property of intersection of sets as $(\exists! C)(\forall x)(x\in C\iff x\in A\land x\in B)$.